# How to capture accurate duration of voice calls in Twilio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I can make voice calls using TwiML, I want to capture the duration only after the caller (the number in the `<Dial>`) starts answering. (Not since the first device answered.) Is there a way to do that?

```
<Response>
<Dial>
<Number>+01234567890</Number>
</Dial>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the `<Number>` you can set a [`statusCallback` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-status-callback) set to a URL that will receive webhook requests for the [events "initiated", "ringing", "answered" and "completed"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-status-callback-event).

Also, a single Twilio call is made up of more than one [Call Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource) for each leg of the call, between Twilio and the participant. So, in your example, your call that starts with the `<Dial><Number>` is different to an existing call that caused the webhook and you can inspect the `duration` property of that call separate to the initial one.

Comment: Thanks a lot!, and I want to know one more thing, I have posted it above. Can you please check it?

Comment: This `statusCallback` URL will then get called from Twilio and you'll be able to measure the duration of the call there. I.e. you need to implement the needed logic in this webhook (e.g. via a Twilio Function) and then use the URL of **this** endpoint, instead of `https://myapp.com/calls/events`, as the TwiML attribute.

Answer (score 0):

How to add `statusCallback` attribute correcty on the `number` attribute? I found an example as follows;

```
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Number
         statusCallbackEvent="initiated ringing answered completed"
         statusCallback="https://myapp.com/calls/events"
         statusCallbackMethod="POST">
            +12316851234
        </Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

But, I can't understand what is the URL used in `statusCallback` attribute? Do you mean adding a webhook URL to it?

Comment: Yes, the `statusCallback` should be a URL in your application that can respond to webhook requests. Please note, it's best to edit your question rather than add an answer with another question in it.